# How to run a background task in react native platform IOS

Tags: javascript, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can i run a background task in react native iOS, currently after my app is cleared from the recent apps the notifications are not being received, any suggestions?

Iam using fcm for push notifications, in android the listeners are working even after the app is terminated but in IOS the listeners are been canceled.